# Ubuntu 20.04: Screen layout not saving after reboot

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I've seen this asked but doesn't seem to get an answer, so here I am haha.

I have a  two monitor setup, main monitor landscape and secondary rotated to the left (See image)

[Nvidia Screen layout Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQci4.png)

I have tried saving the xconfig settings, running it under root etc, but no luck at all and it resets to defaults after reboot. Also the Gnome display settings just refuse to change my screen layout to the left.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,

Nick.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm currently having the same issue. My Nvidia layout won't save on reboot.

Answer (score 2):

Very old question but I had the same issue and it was due to the following:

1. I migrated to the new VM (Ubuntu) from a different machine and used a *different account name*.
2. I copied my old `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` from the old machine.
3. My `.bashrc`/etc had the following: `export HOME=/home/<my old name>`

When I would login as `<new_name>` the wrong name would be imported and the display couldn't find the config files so it just did a default display.

Again, probably not your problem but posting this for other people, just in case.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you ever found a solution for your issue, and this may vary between specific Ubuntu flavors/distros, but I had a very similar problem with UALinux when I upgraded to 20.04.

I discovered there was a .desktop file in the .config/autostart folder that referred to a script in etc/skel which was executing on startup and overwriting many of my layout changes, such as favorites, screensaver, icon sets, and so on. I edited the variables in the script (or commented them out entirely if persistence was not desired) to reflect my preferred choices, saved, fixed my layout, then restarted. This stopped the layout from being reset to default, or rather, it allowed me to change the things I wanted to change while continuing to force settings I will never want changed to remain the same.

It's a handy script to have around in case you do something that messes up your interface and you don't know how to get it back--restarting will just fix it--but annoying if you don't know it's there, since it just overwrites your desktop layout again and again. I imagine you can also just stop the script from running at all by editing the .desktop file in the autostart folder.

I'm pretty new to Linux myself so I don't know if this will be applicable to your situation, but that was my solution, so I hope it helps.